# Disable hibernate hbm2ddl

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot project that uses flyway to insert the database structure and it works perfectly except when testing. When I run my tests I can see that the flyway sql files are executed so that works however for some reason hibernate drops and creates the database structure. This only happens when in testing so it seams as if Spring is telling Hibernate to drop-create the schema when testing.

How can I completly disable the hbm2dll?

I can understand that this is the default behaviour however it this the right thing to do? Spring should never assume that someone wants hbm2dll eneabled when testing, that should be indicated by the user not spring.

Comment: See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-creating-and-dropping-jpa-databases (set it to `none` or `validate`). `

Comment: I did that and unfornately it doenst work. I still see this in the output: 

drop table settings if exists
...

I am using a application.yml file althought that shouldn't matter

Comment: Then you didn't set the correct property I would say or manually are configuring things and thus bypassing the spring boot auto configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your time :). I am switching to ExpressJS for my rest endpoints. Spring boot is way too heavy for simple rest endpoints and configuration is alot easier in ExpressJs.

Comment: set hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate

Comment: For spring boot it should be spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none